# Class App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api does not exist on Broadcasting

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-broadcast, laravel-guard

I am having an issue with the auth:api guard working with broadcasting.

I get the error `Class App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api does not exist` if I call `php artisan route:list`.

BroadcastServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes([
            'prefix' => 'api',
            'middleware' => 'auth:api',
        ]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

config/auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

If I remove the middleware from the BroadcastingServiceProvider for the Broadcast::routes I no longer have the issue.

I am using this same guard `auth:api` in my routes file as well, which seems to be working fine:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {

});
```

I thought perhaps the imports in the `providers` array in config/app.php was the problem, but that doesn't seem to be it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which laravel version is used?

Comment: @Tpojka Newest version 8

Comment: For sake of test try to set another prefix, maybe it's something with rat race between api and broadcast routes and their load/require times.

Comment: @Tpojka Unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: `composer du`? Only I can advice is to go with xdebug line by line and follow while request executes to check why and where is failing.

Comment: Try instead `'middleware' => ['auth:api']`

Comment: @miken32 Nope. Did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

The way I've always protected my channels is adding `Broudcast::routes()` to `api.php` not in the `BroadcastServiceProvider`.

```php
//api.php
Broadcast::routes([
    'middleware' => [
        'auth:api'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Got this error after dong that ```Class Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests:240,1 does not exist```